# How to get Liferay portlet instance id in velocity template

Tags: java, javascript, liferay, portlet, velocity

I'm trying to add a link to a velocity template that calls an action in an instanceable portlet. It looks like this

```
<a href="/mypage?p_p_id=displayportlet_WAR_myportlets_INSTANCE_ia9r3lKTG3YL&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=pop_up&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_pos=1&p_p_col_count=2&_displayportlet_WAR_myportlets_INSTANCE_ia9r3lKTG3YL_struts.portlet.action=%2Fview%2FdisplayCart">click here</a>
```

Is there a way to get the instance id (`ia9r3lKTG3YL`) using the portlet name (`displayportlet_WAR_myportlets`) using javascript or some built in function or do I really have to hardcode it? This template is used for several instances of the same site and the instance ids are different on each site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hard coding portlet ID, Its worth giving a try using Friendly URL mapping concept in liferay.
Using this concept, portlet ID get injected dynamically and URL to portlet is much simpler to use in velocity.

http://www.liferay.com/en_GB/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/FriendlyURLMapper

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using friendly urls

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still looking for an answer, you can get your portlet instance Id in your Velocity template by using the $themeDisplay variable :

`$themeDisplay.getPortletDisplay().getId();`

Hope this helps.